How to use keyboard navigation on items in a ListView nested in a MenuFlyout?
I have a Button that opens a MenuFlyout when pressed. The MenuFlyout has several custom MenuFlyoutItems: One with a nested StackPanel, one that has a bound Command, and one ListView of actionable items (defined with ListView.ItemTemplate). The problem is that when navigating the flyout using the keyboard, I can't access/perform any actions on the items within the ListView, the focus only moves to surround the entire ListView.
No success with arrow keys. I've tried defining TabFocusNavigation="Cycle" and XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled" on the MenuFlyoutItem that wraps the ListView, IsItemClickEnabled="True", TabFocusNavigation="Cycle", and XYFocusKeyboardNavigation="Enabled" on the ListView, and every combination of these. What am I missing here?

Similar to this thread, the workaround is to use Control.Focus(FocusState) Method to set focus state of the ListView when the MenuFlyoutItem gets focus.
1.Get the ListView in event MenuFlyoutItem_GotFocus.
2.Set SelectedIndex and FocusState of ListView to get focus in ListView.
MainPage.xaml
<Button Content="Button" Margin="397,404,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Button.Flyout>
        <MenuFlyout>
            <MenuFlyoutItem>
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <StackPanel >
                            <TextBlock Text="Test" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>

            <MenuFlyoutItem  GotFocus="MenuFlyoutItem_GotFocus">
                <MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ListView Loaded="ListView_Loaded" LostFocus="ListView_LostFocus">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </MenuFlyoutItem.Template>
            </MenuFlyoutItem>

            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Test"></MenuFlyoutItem>
            
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Button.Flyout>
</Button>


MainPage.xaml.cs
  public ObservableCollection<string> IconItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
  private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      {
          IconItems.Add($"index{i}");
      }
      var listview = sender as ListView;
      listview.ItemsSource = IconItems;
   
  }

    public bool isListViewFocus = false;
    private void MenuFlyoutItem_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuFlyoutItem = sender as MenuFlyoutItem;

        ListView listView = FindChild<ListView>(menuFlyoutItem);

        if (listView != null && isListViewFocus == false) 
        {
            if (listView.SelectedIndex == -1) 
            {
                listView.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                listView.SelectedIndex = listView.SelectedIndex;
            }

            listView.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
        }

        isListViewFocus = true;
    }

    private void ListView_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isListViewFocus = false;
    }

    public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent) where T : DependencyObject
    {
        if (parent == null)
            return null;

        int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            if (child is T typedChild)
                return typedChild;

            // Recursively search deeper into nested containers
            T result = FindChild<T>(child);
            if (result != null)
                return result;
        }

        return null; // Child not found
    }

